# Please identify yellow car-like set

Tags: set-identification

I bought a bag of Lego. And one piece was not taken apart fully. Seems like a yellow car. Maybe from Technic series, but not sure. Could be older, like 2009-2014.

[image: yellow-lego]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is [Cool Cruiser (5767)](https://brickset.com/sets/5767-1/Cool-Cruiser) from 2011.

[image]

[image]